# How do I set up Google Analytics to track outbound links? The official example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to track clicks on outbound links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211120/how-to-track-clicks-on-outbound-links)

As described in [the official documentation](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920) I have included this piece of code in my `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    try {
      var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
      _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category , action ]);
      setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
    }catch(err){}
  }
</script>
```

And have changed the link to this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com');return false;">
```

However still no events are shown up in the reports.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the Google Analytics documentation is incorrect. The code in the `<head>` section should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    try {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action ]);
      setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
    }catch(err){}
  }
</script>
```